# Maximizing a function of several variables

Tags: matlab, constraints, mathematical-optimization

As part of a school project, I would like to maximize a rather complicated function F of three variables t1, t2, t3, on the interval 0(<)t1+t2+t3(<=)120. Due to the complexity of the function, I would like to define parameters a,b,c in terms of t1,t2,t3 and in terms of three other parameters x1,x2,x3 which are also in terms of t1,t2,t3. The function F should be written in terms of x1,x2,x3,a,b,c,t1,t2,t3. Is there a straightforward way to do this? I haven't done all of the algebra, but I imagine that the function in its full form would be a polynomial of degree ~15. I am new to Matlab, so please be clear. I would greatly appreciate any help.

The code has the following form:

```
x1=f(t1)

x2=f(t2)

x3=f(t3)
```

[In the code f is written as a mathematical expression; no function is declared. Also, they each contain different constants, though the form is the same]

```
a=g(x1)

b=h(x2,a)

c=i(x3,b,a)
```

Again, g, h, and i refer to mathematical expressions written into the code. No function is declared.

Now the function that I would like to optimize has this form:

F(t1,t2,t3,a,b,c,), which is really F(t1,t2,t3) since (a,b,c) are themselves functions of t1,t2,t3. I would like to optimize the function on the interval 0(<)t1+t2+t3(<=)120.

Answer (score 0):

I´d like see a example, but you can use three arrays. t,a,x like arguments of your function.

Comment: Should I post the entire code? Its rather involved-and it's not annotated. Also, b is defined in terms of a, and c is defined in terms of a and b. x1, x2, and x3 are defined only in terms of t1,t2,and t3 respectively.

Comment: post only declaration of variables and your function

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

1. Just use local variables in your evaluation function.
2. Supply gradients if the solver can use them.
3. Often polynomials with a high degree swing around a lot. They can cause a lot  of troubles for a solver.